# Symfony2 Translator - Check if translation exists

Tags: symfony

I have a problem with symfony2 translations.

I would like to develop a menu translator which detects the right translation-domain.

**Example:**

```
return $this->translator->trans('test', array(), 'crud') == $path ? $this->translator->trans($path) : $this->translator->trans($path, array(), 'crud');
```

But it doesnt work with "dynamic" translations like `edit.%thing`.

I search a function like this:

```
return $this->translator->check('test', 'crud') ? $this->translator->trans('test', array(), 'crud') : $this->translator->trans('test', array());
```

Comment: Symfony detects language autmatically and you can define a fallback locale. Is that not enough for your needs?

Comment: @artworkadシ i mean a fallback for translation -> domain <-! not the translator language...

Answer (score -1):

Try this something like this:

```
$trans = $this->translator->trans('test', array(), 'crud');
if($trans === 'test') {
    // No translation - do something else
}
else {
    // Translation exists
    return $trans;
}
```

This works on the principle that the id will be returned by the trans function is if no translation exists.